# How to setup solution for 32-bit winform that references 64-bit class library?

Tags: c#, winforms, 64-bit

I have two projects in a solution:

`MyWinForm` - a 32-bit project with custom user controls

`MyClassLibrary` - a 64-bit project that requires 64-bit for math operations

I am "forced" by microsoft to generate user controls that are 32-bit assemblies. [See here for reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/963017)

I am "forced" by my math model to require 64-bit math operations.

If I reference `MyClassLibrary`within `MyWinForm`and maintain it as a 64-bit assembly, then my math operations complete with success; however, I can no longer use a custom user control. I get the following error if I try: "failed to load toolbox item it will be removed" when I attempt to drag and drop my custom user control to a designer surface.

If I reference `MyClassLibrary`within `MyWinForm`and maintain it as a 32-bit assembly, then my math operations fail with a OutOfMemory exception (due to 32-bit max size limitation).

How can I setup my solution to allow both a custom user control AND a 64-bit class library to be referenced, avoiding the issues?

I'd really like to be able to use the toolbox and design surface. I have a hunch that I'm going to need to load the custom user control at run-time, so that the dynamic compiler knows how to decided 32 or 64 bit. This defeats the purpose of using a Visual IDE in my opinion.

Comment: You can't use a 64b library in a 32b process as the library is loaded on the process space thus must be 32b

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: well, at a first not anything direct, but you can create two separate processes, one for the 32b GUI and other with the 64b math classes and intercomunicate them with tcp/pipes/shared memory, you can start the 32b, that launches a non-visible process and then you can mix things. A tip, an stack overflow happens because there's no stack left, did you tried to rise the stack size on the 32b process?

Comment: What problems do you run into if you change all of your 32-bit components to AnyCPU?

Comment: @OldFart: I have just one 32-bit component which is the winforms project, and indeed when I set it to AnyCpu it causes my 64-bit class library to run as 32-bit.

Comment: Make sure to clear "prefer 32bit" checkbox too - real question is if you have any problems running your WinForm app as x64 (it is clear that design time need to be x86, but it should have no impact on actually running the app)

Comment: @Gusman: My apologies, I listed the wrong exception: i'm actually getting an out of memory exception when my math library attempts to initialize an array with more than <some large number> of elements.

Comment: Then the best you can do is the solution with two processes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a workaround. I realized that my goal is to use the Visual Designer, which runs in 32-bit, so that I didn't have to write any of my own code. Here is what I did:

1. set `WinForms` project to be 32-bit.
2. Created a `custom user control`.
3. Build project in 32-bit.
4. Drag and drop `custom user control` on to design surface.
5. Specify all properties of `custom user control`. (color, size, dock, etc.)
6. Declare a `Form_OnLoad()` method.
7. Copy/paste all auto-generated code from the designer code-behind that related to my custom user control in to `Form_OnLoad()`.
8. Delete all design elements from design surface related to `custom user control`. This will remove auto-generated code in the designer code-behind for the `custom user control`.
9. Build and test: do I see the `custom user control`? yes..proceed.
10. Switch the build settings back to 64-bit for the WinForms project.
11. Build and test: do I see the `custom user control`? yes..execute math function...does it work without any exceptions? yes..proceed

This quick and dirty workaround is not ideal - but was very fast to implement. Switching my project to be 32-bit temporarily to active the Visual IDE is "no big deal" for this project.

**** EDIT TO SOLUTION ****

Do not do the above. Instead see Hans comment below.

Admins: sorry for the sloppy Post, feel free to delete this as I don't know if this question and answer will help anyone else but me.

Comment: Surely you are chasing the wrong solution, the issue is that your math library is also used in design mode.  And dies because now it runs in 32-bit mode.  You do not want to use your library in design mode, there is no point to that.  Not much point in allocating massive amounts of memory in the Debug build either btw.

Comment: If your GUI code runs fine in both 32-bit and 64-bit, then you can probably streamline the development process by adding another project: (1) "WinForms" executable, 64-bit build, contains just Program.cs (2) WinForms class library DLL that contains the actual UI, AnyCPU build, (3) Math class library DLL, 64-bit build.  In this case the UI DLL should load into both the 32-bit designers and the 64-bit application without needing to mess with settings ever again.

Comment: @Hans: you are absolutely correct. To test out your theory I created interfaces for my math library. I moved those interfaces to a 'model' class library. I then removed completely the 64-bit math library reference from my winforms project. I then changed the winforms project to be "AnyCpu" - and verified correct operation. No errors. Thanks you Hans for the accurate observation.

Comment: @Hans: I'm permuting every five card hand that can be dealt from a deck of 52 cards using integers as indexes (52C5) etc. times the number of pay categories in a standard video poker game. That object graph size exceeds 32-bit limit. Seems like I need the space...and there is point to it.

Comment: Just don't leave info like that out of the question, you'll only ever get useful answers when you share enough details.